# WordPress redirection plugin database update issue

Tags: wordpress, redirection

I am using [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) plugin to manage my redirections on my wordpress site.

After updating to version 4.7 the plugin indicates that an update of the redirection database is necessary. Doing so however breaks the functionality of the plugin completely.

I was able to manually set the database version back to it's prior value, which made the plugin work again, however prompting me to update the database again.

According to [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/redirections-database-needs-to-be-updated-after-updating/), I further tried to clear my caches with W3 Total Cache to avoid the plugin from prompting me to update the database without success.

The database is currently version 2.4 and would be updated to version 4.1. Wordpress is running as version 4.19.13. Shell-access to the server is given.

I'd like to avoid updating wordpress as a whole for now, as I can't predict whether any workflow issues will arise.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the plugin again to gain some error information mysteriously worked without problems.

The issue does no longer persist.